# How to see if a Promise contains specific data using Chai assertions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, chai

I've started using the Chakram Rest API testing framework which utilizes the Chai assertion library.  In my code below Chakram.get returns a Promise.  I can't seem to figure out how to see if this promise contains what I am specfically looking for.  For example, Chakram.get should've got back the following string:

```
[
 "category1",
 "category2"
]
```

I simply want to see if it contains "category1".

```
var chakram = require('chakram'),
    expect = chakram.expect;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

describe("Categories", function() {
    it("should return the list of categories for devices that are installed in the project", function () {
        var response = chakram.get("https://192.168.2.2/category");
        expect(response).to.have.status(200);
        expect(response).not.to.have.header('non-existing-header');
        expect(response).to.contain('category1');
        return chakram.wait();
    });
});
```

As you can see, I've tried the above to.contain line but get the following exception.  I assume it is because Chai doesn't like the object type.  Not sure if I need to convert the Promise to a different object type?  If so, how?

```
TypeError: obj.indexOf is not a function
  at include (/Users/acme/node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:228:45)
  at /Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:304:26
  at _fulfilled (/Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
  at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
  at /Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
  at runSingle (/Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
  at flush (/Users/acme/node_modules/chakram/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `response.body`

```
expect(response.body).to.contain('category1');
```

here is an example with the full promise:

```
  it("should support sequential API interaction", function () {
    return chakram.get("url")
    .then(function (response) {
      expect(response.body).to.contain("thing");
    });
  });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Error message changed to "AssertionError: object tested must be an array, an object, or a string, but undefined given" so it seems as ''body" is undefined.

Comment: can you post the full `describe` block? is your status = 200 assertion passing if you exclude the response body check?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example with the full promise - give that a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can stringify response.body and then use index of function to check if it contains whatever you are expecting.